# How to plot values associated to a string array in a pandas df?

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, plot, python-3.7

I think my question is easy to solve.
I have a simple dataframe with this shape:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+
| Age_Group  | Gene_Name |   Degree |
+------------+-----------+----------+
| pediatric  | JAK2      |       17 |
| adult      | JAK2      |       14 |
| AYA        | JAK2      |       11 |
| pediatric  | ETV6      |       52 |
| adult      | ETV6      |        7 |
| AYA        | ETV6      |        4 |
```

Then it continues repeating for others genes.

My goal is to plot the degree values on the y-axis with different colors depends on the Age Group and the gene names on the x-axis but I have no idea how to make gene names suitable for python plotting function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot the data frame and plot. If you want to rename gene names, that can be done beforehand using replace or map.

```
df.pivot(index = 'Gene_Name', columns = 'Age_Group',values = 'Degree').plot.bar()
```

[image]